# On convergence of the series $\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\binom{k-1}{2}p^3(1-p)^{k-3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a number $0 \le p \le 1$ calculate if:

$\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty \binom{k-1}{2} p^{3}(1-p)^{k-3} = 1 $

So:
$\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty \binom{k-1}{2} p^{3} (1-p)^{k-3} = \sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{2}(k-1)(k-2) p^{3} (1-p)^{k-3} = 
\frac{p^{3}}{2}\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty (k-1)(k-2) (1-p)^{k-3} =
\frac{p^{3}}{2}\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty \frac{d^2}{dp^{2}} (1-p)^{k-1}=
\frac{p^{3}}{2} \frac{d^2}{dp^{2}}\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty  (1-p)^{k-1}=
\frac{p^{3}}{2} \frac{d^2}{dp^{2}} ( \frac{(1-p)^{2}}{p}) = \frac{p^{3}}{2} \frac{d}{dp} ( 1-\frac{1}{p^{2}}) = 1
$

Is it solved in the right way?

Comment: **Hint:** Exchange then order of summation and differentiation.

Comment: @user3535688: The second derivative of $\dfrac{(1-p)^2}p$ with regard to *p* is $0$ ?

Comment: The derivative I wrote was wrong

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.